# word problem speed and time

Tags: word-problem

I found the answer non-algebraically, 
E drove from city 1 at 80 km/h, A left city 1 an hour later and drove at 100 km/h (on same road). How far into the road will A overtake E.

I found that it will be 400 km in, but I can't do it algebraically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let speed of E by S, S=80km/h, let speed of A be S'=100km/h

We are going to need to use the formula velocity=distance/time (v=d/t)

And we are looking to find at what distance the cars have the same location.

For E in one hour we have, 80= distance/1 hour= 80km traveled,

Using the diffirence S'-S we know that car A is travelling 20km/h faster than car E

t=80km/h/20km , t=4 hours to catch up from start, so they meet at 100km/h(4hours)=d=400km